# Основы цилиндра не отображаются! Где задать openEnded (three.js)?

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

Я создал объект в `Blender` и загрузил его:

*Код:*

```
var cylinder_texture = new THREE.Texture();
var loader_cylinder = new THREE.ImageLoader();

loader_cylinder.load('js/1.png', function(image){
    cylinder_texture.image = image;
    cylinder_texture.needsUpdate = true;
}); 

// model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'js/2.obj', function ( object ) {

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            child.material.map = cylinder_texture;

        }

    } );

    object.position.x = -30;
    object.position.y = 130;
    object.position.z = 250;
    object.rotation.x = 20 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.rotation.y = -50 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.rotation.z = 0 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.scale.x = 30;
    object.scale.y = 20;
    object.scale.z = 20;
    obj = object
    scene.add( obj );

    animation();
    function animation () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animation);

        obj.rotation.x += 180/Math.PI*0.001;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }


    renderer.render(scene, camera);
} );
```

Отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно так (с верхушкой и низушкой):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

свойства `child.material.openEnded` нету.

Вопрос в том, где и что нужно указать, чтобы появились основы цилиндра и он не был сквозной.

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно, что экспорт из Blender'а происходит криво.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразуйте объект в меш <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -> **Convert to Mesh**

Меш, как более стандартная фигура, отобразится верно.

Хотя если у вас уже меш, тогда предположу, что не отображаются bMesh - грани, у которых больше четырех точек. Чтобы исправить это, при экспорте триангулируйте меш:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]